# Portably testing for folders in C++?

Tags: c++, stat, dirent.h

My basic problem is that this piece of code almost always throws an exception:

```
bool DirectoryRange::isDirectory() const
{
    struct stat s;
    stat(ep->d_name, &s);

#if defined(__linux__)
    if((S_ISDIR(s.st_mode) != 0) != (ep->d_type == DT_DIR))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Directory is not directory");
    }
#endif

    return S_ISDIR(s.st_mode);
}

bool DirectoryRange::isFile() const
{
    struct stat s;
    stat(ep->d_name, &s);

#if defined(__linux__)
    if((S_ISREG(s.st_mode) != 0) != (ep->d_type == DT_REG))
    {
        throw std::logic_error("File is not file");
    }
#endif

    return S_ISREG(s.st_mode);
}
```

Checking the dirent value is not portable, but is getting the right answer; while stat is wrong, but is portable.

So how can I check for directories portably if stat doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Try Boost.Filesystem.

Comment: Minor pedantic trivia here, but not all filesystems have the concept of folders.  The mainframe, in particular, does not.  Hopefully, you'll never need to know this, but just in case... well, there it is.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `S_ISDIR` is [not a macro that returns a boolean value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html):

> The macro **evaluates to a non-zero value** if the test is true, 0 if the
>   test is false.
>
> ...
>
> S_ISDIR(m) - Test for a directory.

(emphasis mine). The explicit casts to `bool` are wrong, and accomplish nothing useful. The correct way to use this macro (and other `S_..` macros) is, simply:

```
 if(S_ISDIR(s.st_mode) == 0)
 {
      throw std::logic_error("Directory is not a Directory");
 }
```

Comment: I made the changes but that didn't fix it; anyway I noticed the error before adding the exception, because it tries to open files as folders.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be most reliable:

```
bool DirectoryRange::isDirectory() const
{
#if defined(__linux__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
    return ep->d_type == DT_DIR;
#else 
    auto path = syspath();
    DIR * dp = opendir(path.c_str());
    if(dp) closedir(dp);
    return dp;
#endif
}

bool DirectoryRange::isFile() const
{
#if defined(__linux__) || (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
    return ep->d_type == DT_REG;
#else 
    auto path = syspath();
    FILE * fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "r");
    if(fp) fclose(fp);
    return fp;
#endif
}
```